# Cannot find elpy-format-code

Tags: formatting, elpy

I have `yapf` installed, and would like to run it automatically. Documentation says there is a way: http://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ide.html#command-elpy-format-code but I don't see it in the source code.

PS. It's not important that it come from Elpy. If there's an alternative ready-made solution, it's just as good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elpy-format-code is [available in elpy](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/blob/c3fb8a8a4aaa7aafec6a38d22ffe1731e7a8cf20/elpy.el#L2272). You can run it with `C-c C-r f` or `M-x elpy-format-code`.

If you want to run it automatically, you can use buffer hooks or a timer to run whenever you want.

Comment: Can you tell when was this added? I have 1.8.0 and it doesn't have this function.

Comment: It is added [in  1.11](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/commit/5c23a2285fc6728d1b8da7408b34dda147d72fda). Current version is 1.15.

Comment: For some reason is not loading during the normal setup process. I have to load the elpy.el file directly for the function to be defined.

Comment: Are you loading elpy in your init file? @MarceloLacerda

Comment: Oh silly me I was not doing `(elpy-enable)` in the init file.